# JQuery DatePicker for input type=date IE11 Error: Object doesn't support property or method swap

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the html5 tag:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date">
```

this works on phones en microsoft edge browser but not on internet explorer. to get it to work on IE11, I added the following:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
```

When I click on the calendar in IE11, I get the following error:
Object doesn't support property or method swap.

I am using the following JQuery sources:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script> 
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't get it to work, now I am using this: <script>if ( $('#date')[0].type != 'date' ) $('#date').datepicker();</script>

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in webshim. https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/issues/560 states two possible workarounds

1. re-instate the swap function. I tested by putting it in a jquery-swap.js file, and included it after jquery.

jquery-swap.js:

```
jQuery.swap = function( elem, options, callback, args ) {
  var ret, name, old = {};
  // Remember the old values, and insert the new ones



  for ( name in options ) {
        old[ name ] = elem.style[ name ];
        elem.style[ name ] = options[ name ];
  }

  ret = callback.apply( elem, args || [] );

  // Revert the old values
  for ( name in options ) {
          elem.style[ name ] = old[ name ];
  }
  return ret;
};
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-swap.js"></script>
```

2. roll back jquery to 1.11.3

It would be nice if the dependencies were clearly stated.